# Using Case field as parameter column in stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters, case

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rpt_Report]
   @Product varchar(20) = NULL,
   @From DateTime = null,
   @To DateTime = null
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
       CO.PO, CO.DLVRY,   
       CASE
          WHEN co.CUST_ID = '120' THEN '120' 
          WHEN HDR.PO_NO LIKE 'CL%' THEN 'CL'
          WHEN RED.REU = 'SK' THEN 'STOCK' 
          WHEN RED.REU = 'SM' THEN 'ORTS' 
          WHEN co.ITEM = 'PW%' THEN 'CHAIN' 
          WHEN co.ITEM LIKE 'D%' THEN 'VAN' ELSE 'MISC' 
       END AS PRODUCT 
     FROM   
        co AS co    
     INNER JOIN 
        HDR AS HDR ON co.NUMBER = HDR.NUMBER 
     INNER JOIN 
        RED AS RED ON co.ITEM = RED.ITEM 
     WHERE   
        (co.DLVRY BETWEEN @From AND @To) AND (@Product = PRODUCT)
     ORDER BY
        co.DLVRY DESC
END
```

When I execute it I am getting an error saying

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure rpt_Report, Line 34
>   Invalid column name 'PRODUCT'.

I should use the case field value as parameter in where CLAUSE.

Comment: try removing the comma after PRODUCT

Comment: Remove the comma from the `... END AS Product ,` before the `FROM` keyword - that comma is not needed and causes this error....

Comment: hi devak & marc, the comma was added by mistake.even after removing the comma the same error is occuring. what i need is, the product_type field value, which should be used as a value for @product in where clause. But since the Product_type field is not a column from any of the above tables, its throwing an error as invalid column.

Comment: Are `PRODUCT_TYPE` (in `WHERE`) and `PRODUCT` (in `SELECT`) meant to be the same column?

Comment: then what is this PRODUCT_TYPE column.If its not from any table then how would you expect it to get the value.

Comment: sorry its not product_type, its product only

Comment: is the `PRODUCT` in the `WHERE` clause supposed to be the value from the `CASE` statement?

Comment: yes the product value from the case statement should be a parameter value in where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are attempting to use the `PRODUCT` alias in the `WHERE` clause, which you cannot do.  So you can wrap the query in a sub-query to use the alias:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rpt_Report]
   @Product varchar(20) = NULL,
   @From DateTime = null,
   @To DateTime = null
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT x.PO, x.DLVRY, x.PRODUCT
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CO.PO, CO.DLVRY,   
           CASE
              WHEN co.CUST_ID = '120' THEN '120' 
              WHEN HDR.PO_NO LIKE 'CL%' THEN 'CL'
              WHEN RED.REU = 'SK' THEN 'STOCK' 
              WHEN RED.REU = 'SM' THEN 'ORTS' 
              WHEN co.ITEM = 'PW%' THEN 'CHAIN' 
              WHEN co.ITEM LIKE 'D%' THEN 'VAN' ELSE 'MISC' 
           END AS PRODUCT 
         FROM  co AS co    
         INNER JOIN HDR AS HDR 
            ON co.NUMBER = HDR.NUMBER 
         INNER JOIN RED AS RED 
            ON co.ITEM = RED.ITEM 
    ) x        
    WHERE (x.DLVRY BETWEEN @From AND @To) 
        AND (@Product = PRODUCT)
    ORDER BY x.DLVRY DESC
END
```

Comment: are you ure that you have data?  can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data?

Comment: without the Product parameter i am able to fetch the data

Comment: @sateesh if you run the query outside of the stored procedure, does it work with the parameter?

Comment: i didn't use @Product as parameter

Comment: @sateesh can you post some sample data or create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?  Or place `RTRIM()`/`LTRIM()` around the `PRODUCT` value in the `WHERE` clause in the event there is whitespace>

Comment: it worked for me when i edited the Query with "AS X" at "X".Thanks A Lot for all who tried to help me

Comment: @sateesh glad you figured it out.  If any of the answers were helpful, then be sure to accept it via the checkmark on the left. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
SELECT 
   CO.PO, CO.DLVRY,   
   PRODUCT = CASE
                WHEN co.CUST_ID = '120' THEN '120' 
                WHEN HDR.PO_NO LIKE 'CL%' THEN 'CL'
                WHEN RED.REU = 'SK' THEN 'STOCK' 
                WHEN RED.REU = 'SM' THEN 'ORTS' 
                WHEN co.ITEM = 'PW%' THEN 'CHAIN' 
                WHEN co.ITEM LIKE 'D%' THEN 'VAN' ELSE 'MISC' 
             END 
 FROM   
    co AS co    
 INNER JOIN 
    HDR AS HDR ON co.NUMBER = HDR.NUMBER 
 INNER JOIN 
    RED AS RED ON co.ITEM = RED.ITEM 
 WHERE   
    (co.DLVRY BETWEEN @From AND @To) AND (@Product = PRODUCT)
 ORDER BY
    co.DLVRY DESC
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: I tried this method but i am getting "Must declare the scalar variable "@Product"." as error.

Comment: @sateesh, here is an example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6816/2 and all is working correctly.